# Are questions about industrial control on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

This [question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-to-map-the-identity-and-control-of-slave-devices-behind-the-programmable-log) could arguably be described as in the retrocomputing realm of IoT. Although the protocol in question is 30 years old, the use case seems to align with industrial IoT applications.

So for this specific question, its a little unclear what the question is about, but it seems the general subject is on-topic. It seems unlikely that the experts in this area will be any more active in a more conventional networking forum. If anything, I'd suggest Electronic Engineering is likely to be the closest match.

One option is to identify a technological step or date which allows a choice of if a specific question is IoT, or simply a question about working with a legacy implementation.

Answer (score 9):

I think we **should** allow these questions, even if the original protocol is quite old now. Although IoT often uses quite new technologies, I see nothing wrong with accepting questions that use older technology, so long as the question still relates to networking devices together in some form to sense and respond to the outside world.

Industrial IoT is (or at least should be) a valid topic for this site, and questions will naturally have some elements of electronics, embedded computing and perhaps even robotics. I think we should accept this, and understand that not all questions will directly relate to the **Internet** of Things, but perhaps smaller, more local networks.

So, in short, **yes, that question is on-topic, even though there isn't a direct link to Internet networking**.

Comment: Actually, the question is about *an* Internet, which is to say a network of networks.  And the dilemma posed is very relevant to other sorts of IoT - there are lots of cases where various devices on a unique network are then bridged to an IP network.  This is also a good demonstration of the common observation that "IoT" is 50% hype, *40% trendy re-branding of things people were already doing* and only 10% new.  There may well be a problem with the question, but that is missing information, not relevance to the site mission.

Comment: @ChrisStratton indeed, but my point was rather that connection to **the** Internet isn't relevant - individual networks can still participate in the Internet of Things without connecting to the actual Internet.